# turning problem left side only

Tags: maintenance

Hi I have a 2014 dodge grand caravan crew. I have own it for three years now.My problem is when I sharply turn left,theirs a loud grinding noise coming from the front end somewhere.I have changed the break shoes on all four calipers.Also just changed all tires.I can't seem to find where the noise is coming from.Please help...

Comment: Is it a clicking sound or definitely a grinding?  CV joints tend to fall more into the clicking category.  Check for loose fender liner?  Can someone stand outside the van and hear it better?